# unexpected T_STRING error in Collabpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to debug the Collabpress plugin for WordPress. My knowledge of PHP is very basic.

The error is in one php file called cp-loader.php. The error is unexpected T_STRING on line 88, which is highlighted below. The code is the following:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: CollabPress
Plugin URI: http://collabpress.org/
Description: A Project Management Plugin for WordPress
Version: 1.3.1.2
Author: WebDevStudios.com
Author URI: http://webdevstudios.com/
License: GPLv2
*/

/*  Copyright 2011  WebDevStudios  (email : contact@webdevstudios.com)

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as
published by the Free Software Foundation.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

// CollabPress Define(s)
define( 'CP_VERSION', '1.3.1.2' );

if ( ! defined( 'CP_BASENAME' ) ) {
define( 'CP_BASENAME', plugin_basename(__FILE__) );
}

if ( ! defined( 'CP_PLUGIN_DIR' ) ) {
define( 'CP_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
}

if ( ! defined( 'CP_PLUGIN_URL' ) ) {
define( 'CP_PLUGIN_URL', plugins_url( substr( CP_BASENAME, 0, strpos( CP_BASENAME, '/' ) ) ) .           '/' );
}

define( 'CP_RSS_URL', 'http://collabpress.org/feed' );

// Before CollabPress
do_action( 'cp_before_collabpress' );

//front-end querystring support
$cp_qs_add = cp_frontend_querystrings();

// Define the dashboard link
$cp_dashboard = ( is_admin() ) ? 'admin.php?page=collabpress-dashboard' : '?' .$cp_qs_add.         'cp=front';

// If we're processing an AJAX request,
// set the dashboard link according to the origin of the request
if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['data']['collabpress_ajax_request_origin'] ) ) {
$cp_dashboard = ( $_REQUEST['data']['collabpress_ajax_request_origin'] == 'admin' ) ? 'admin.php?        page=collabpress-dashboard' : '?' .$cp_qs_add. 'cp=front';
}

define( 'CP_DASHBOARD', $cp_dashboard );

// CollabPress Core
require_once( 'includes/cp-core.php' );

 // activation hook
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cp_activation' );


/**
* Returns the query string of CollabPress values
* e.g. task=3&task-list=4
*/
function cp_frontend_querystrings() {

// grab any query strings that exist
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$cp_all_querystrings = ( $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] ) ? $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : '';
$cp_querystrings = explode( '&', $cp_all_querystrings );
} else {
$vars = $_GET;
}

//set pattern to strip out
$pattern = "/^cp|project|task-list|task|view|activity_page/";
$cp_qs_add = '';

foreach ((array) ( '$cp_querystrings as $cp_querystring') 
     -->    preg_match ( '$pattern, $cp_querystring ' ) {  <-- line 88: unexpected T_STRING error
        $cp_qs_add .= $cp_querystring .'&';
    }
}

if ( $cp_qs_add != '&' ) :
    return $cp_qs_add;
endif;

}
```

I've highlighted the error with arrows above. There is an unexpected error on line 88 of "unexpected T_STRING error".

Any help I can get would be great. As this is an open source project on Github, I'll also post something on Github if it works.

Answer (score 0):

A typical foreach-loop looks like this:
`foreach($some_array as $item)` where $some_array is an Array.
Foreach iterates over every item contained in the Array.

But in your Code, you are using a String. Visible by the quotes that surround the text `'$cp_querystrings as $cp_querystring'`. This is the main error in your code.
To solve this error you are trying to convert the String into an Array. This meets the needs of the Foreach loop. But unfortunately PHP is really generous with converting types, so the real cause is not shown in your error message.

Nearly same Problem with `preg_match ( '$pattern, $cp_querystring ' )`.

You `'$pattern, $cp_querystring '` is a single String and therefor only a single parameter for preg_match.

Next problem is the missing if-clause for preg_match.

I put the Solution into this fix:

`foreach ($cp_querystrings as $cp_querystring) {
     if( preg_match ($pattern, $cp_querystring) > 0 ) { 
        $cp_qs_add .= $cp_querystring .'&';
    }
}`

The code you have, is overall broken and won't work on any PHP-Installation. Maybe you've received a version where active development is in Progress?

Comment: Thanks. When I do that I get unexpected '{' on line 88. Could there be something missing in the previous lines/code?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed a { after the foreach. I corrected this in my Post.